# Social Media Login and SIgnUp through PHP

Tags: php

I am implementing Social media login for my website through Linkedin, Twitter and Google. For sign Up it works correctly for all three, but at the time of Login it should not ask for the authentication of the website because user has already authenticated the website at the first step of sign up.

My requirement is that user will only be require to authenticate the website once (at the signup where social media sites asks the user "Allow this website to access your username , fist name etc.. ") and if the same user chooses to Login with same social media , then it should be only asked for credentials and not for "authentication for the website ("Allow this website to see your username , first name etc...")". I searched for this on google for all, but every time it only gives information for signup and not for Login.

**UPDATED**

Below are steps for the above using Google Signin. For this i have used help from the link "http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php"

Step 1. User comes first time. Goes to Sign Up page and presses Sign Up with google. Redirects to Google page, enter the credentials and then Google asks the user whether it should wamt the website to have personal data (First name, last name etc.). User accepts it and returns back to the website.

Step 2. At the website , code check if user id and email is already present in DB for the user or not, if its not present then it register with same user id and type and name for the user and allows him to enter website. There is no storing of password for my website for any social media . Every time they will enter credential at the google only.

Step 3. Next when same user comes, it goes to login page, click on google icon, goes to Google page, enter credentials, but this time google should not ask the user to "Allow this website to share you personal data", instead it should just returns back to website and user will be allowed to enter the website after checking that user data returned from Google are already present in DB.

Please help me out guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? At least, how do you think this can be done? (What APIs have you looked up, etc.)

Comment: And how do you store said access tokens and profiles/etc...?

Answer (score 0):

For the social login facebook,twitter,linkedin offer api for the same.
We need to api call and validate all the things by the api only.
For the facebook we want to crate new app on the facebook and same for the twitter also.

And only required secret key and authentication key....

Comment: Yes you are correct, but next time if user logs in, then user should no tbe asked to allow the website to share personal data. It should return back to the website. Please check my question again, i updated it some more text.